# Push a View Controller in a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab view controller with a navigation controller. In the first tab item I click on a button in a view that pops up a view with animated: YES.

Then when that view is done I hit another button that dismisses it. Like:

```
                   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

                        ProfilesViewController *profile = [[ProfilesViewController alloc] init];
                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];

                        //SHOW YOUR NEW VIEW CONTROLLER HERE!
                    }];
```

But everytime this code runs, it dismisses the view, DOES NOT push the profiles controller, and shows the view from the first tab bar item.

How do I push the ProfilesViewController to the screen with a Back arrow?

Comment: Try presenting the viewcontroller by making it as root to a navigation controller. Then push the `ProfilesViewController` from that viewcontroller itself.

Comment: Which one do I set as root

Comment: Make the presented view controller as root to a navigationcontroller. And push the `ProfilesViewController`, then after completing the task call `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `dismissViewControllerAnimated` to dismiss that means that the VC is presented modally. As such, it doesn't have a navigation controller (so `self.navigationController` is nil) and thus it can't push anything into the navigation controller.

You should really add a property to the controller which is a delegate or a completion block which can be used to push the controller from another controller (the one that presents it) to dismiss and push the controller.

A second option is to pass the navigation controller, it's a similar amount of code to using a block but not so good.

A crappy option is to use the `parentViewController` to find the appropriate navigation controller, but that sucks for many reasons.

Comment: So the tab view controller has 4 viewcontrollers. And on each is a button that pops up the code above and dismisses it. Where do I create the property?

Comment: The property is added to the VC that is popped up, because it needs a delegate to tell when it is complete so that the delegate can push your other VC

Comment: Not 100 percent on how to properly implement it

Comment: Does this part above "You should really add a property to the controller which is a delegate or a completion block which can be used to push the controller from another controller (the one that presents it) to dismiss and push the controller" get added to the start controller

Comment: The start controller is the delegate - it wants to know when the modal is complete (so it can push, and it should also do the dismiss)

Comment: Look at the way https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html works as an example

Comment: Yeah I'm using that one in the modal

Comment: Okay if my start view controller is a tab bar controller does that matter?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter to the delegate what it is, so long as it implements the protocol

Comment: So I create a protocol in the tabbar vc. The methods in that protocol will handleDismiss and postWithPicture. Then the modal will call those functions or does the tab bar vc handle those?

Comment: Create the protocol in the modal, the tab controller implements them and sets its self as the delegate when it creates the modal.